# Bluetooth problem

Tags: bluetooth

I wanted to try out the Bluetooth function today on my Raspberry Pi 3. I turned on Bluetooth on the RPi3 and turned on Bluetooth on my headphones. It said can't connect to headphones try with sound system. So I did that, it connected. Then when I try playing a video, no sound comes out of my headphones.

Is there a fix?

Answer (score 1):

yes, try these codes in terminal. 
First install blueman and pulseaudio.

```
sudo apt-get install blueman pulseaudio pavucontrol pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
```

then start pulseaudio

```
pulseaudio --start
bluetoothctl
```

the above code will give you the list of nearby bluetooth devices.
now pair your headphones by these line

```
pair XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

replace you mac address of headphones as shown in the nearby list then

```
connect XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

if it is connected then it will show Connection successful
these worked for me...

Comment: Sorry doesn't work for me. Everything worked until i tested it by watching a video. No audio came through. Guess will have to revert to a cord.

Comment: try info XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX and see the information of bluetooth device it will show complete detail @DarkestN2O

Answer (score 0):

Found out how to fix it:

1. switch off bluetooth on pi
2. turn on bluetooth on headphones to make it discoverable
3. turn on bluetooth on pi and connect to headphones
4. Thats it! watch your vids/music.